# Summation of a series, possibly simmilar poisson ditribution formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, poisson-distribution

I have the following sum and obviously i need to calculate it.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2\lambda)^k}{k!}$$
What is the simplest method to find this sum? I was thinking about matching this with Poisson distribution, unfortunately i have no idea how to approach that.

Comment: For a $\mathrm{Poisson}(\alpha)$ distribution, the pmf is $f_\alpha(k) = e^{-\alpha} \frac{\alpha^k}{k!}$. Note that since it is a pmf, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_\alpha(k) = 1$... using $\alpha=2\lambda$, what do you get?

Comment: @ClementC. but how could i apply that if there is no $e$ in my formula?

Comment: This is what is missing... so multiply by it on both sides to see the cancellation: $e^{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_\alpha(k) = e^{\alpha}$. (And $e^{\alpha}e^{-\alpha} = 1$ for the LHS.)

Comment: thus the result is 1 or $e^{2\lambda}$?

Comment: Have you tried the above? You want $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2\lambda)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{2\lambda} f_{2\lambda}(k)= e^{2\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_{2\lambda}(k)$. Given the previous comments, what should it be?

Comment: Now i get it! Obviously $e^{2\lambda}$, appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that according to [(one of the) definitions of $\exp$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition), this follows from the very definition (without using Poisson distributions).